# Should we have a [reactive-programming] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

> In computing, reactive programming is a programming paradigm oriented around data flows and the propagation of change. This means that it should be possible to express static or dynamic data flows with ease in the programming languages used, and that the underlying execution model will automatically propagate changes through the data flow.

The tag [reactive-programming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reactive-programming) was recently created for [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98565/sending-file-through-socket). The asker originally created the tags [rxjs](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rxjs) and [socket.io](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/socket.io) for the question, but I removed them in an edit as I didn't think tags should be created without a good case. My edit prompted the asker to create [reactive-programming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reactive-programming) instead. I don't know anything about this programming paradigm which is why I've come here to ask.

14 questions currently match [`reactive is:question`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=reactive%20is%3Aquestion) and are tagged with the names of various frameworks ([system.reactive](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system.reactive), [react.js](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/react.js) etc).

We have the tags [oop](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oop) (discussed recently [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5560/when-should-oop-be-instantiated)) and [functional-programming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming). The reactive programming paradigm seems to be more "meta" as it can be applied in both object oriented and functional programming.

Comment: It should be noted that we have [[tag:frp]] too...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[reactive-programming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reactive-programming) no longer exists.

The question mentioned "frp", so I edited the question to use the existing [frp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frp) tag.

I don't know lickity-split about reactive programming, but everything I've seen about it seems to refer to it as "functional", [even when it's used in object-oriented languages](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/83072/36366).

If there is such a thing as object-oriented reactive-programming, then I suggest we use [reactive-programming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reactive-programming) for *all* reactive-programming questions and synonymize [frp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frp) into [reactive-programming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reactive-programming).  But if there isn't, then [frp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frp) should do.

Someone who knows more about reactive programming should chime in and let us know whether or not we should ever consider needing both tags.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, reactive programming is mostly functional in nature, even in hybrid OO/functional languages. [tag:frp] should suffice.

Answer (score 4):

I'm actually far more concerned about the removal of [socket.io](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/socket.io). It seems to have been a legitimately created tag. [socket.io is a realtime application framework](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io). We have a history of allowing library/framework tags, so I would like to hear some justification for its removal before I go add it back to the question...

Comment: On a similar note, I think that [tag:rxjs] ([Reactive Extensions for JavaScript](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS)) is a valid tag. We already have [tag:rx-java], [tag:system.reactive] (Rx.NET), and [tag:reactive-cocoa], which are all part of the [ReactiveX family](http://reactivex.io/languages.html).

Comment: I thought [tag:socket.io] is essentially the same as [tag:websockets], but upon further inspection, I realise that I'm wrong.

Comment: @mjolka That's probably true too. I think I shouldn't have edited the tags out in the first place.

Comment: I started a new meta about [tag:socket.io] here @jacwah http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5834/too-much-socket-or-not-enough