# Should we clean up our sockets?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Sparked by [this meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5833/41243), I did a [quick search](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=socket.io) for "socket.io" and came back with 21 hits. It seems to be enough to create a tag for it IMO, but I'm no web guy. I don't really understand what this framework is and if it really applies to these questions.

A lot of these questions are currently tagged with [websocket](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/websocket) or [socket](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/socket) and I have a feeling that these tags were just "close enough" when the OPs posted and don't really apply, but I'm not really sure. Can a subject matter expert chime in and let us know if it a [socket.io](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/socket.io) tag would be appropriate on these questions? If so, perhaps someone would be willing to take a look at retagging? It's only 21 questions. It shouldn't take more than a lazy Sunday for one person to clean this up.

Comment: Did you edit bump this because you feel today is a lazy Sunday?

Comment: @nhgrif kind of. Still no answer, so I thought a new title might be clearer and draw one in.

Comment: that is a funny title question - and it did suck me in!  :)  personally I think there should be **no** web-related questions on here .. this site is about actual code, right?  *ducks*  :)

Comment: @JoeBlow I'm not getting what you're saying. The web is built on code and this is Code Review. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm just being funny, dude.  It's not real code unless it's machine code right?  :)  Anyway nice question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just looking around our site tags and checking if I could clean anything up. Noticed we didn't have a [socket.io](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/socket.io) tag, **I think we should have one.**

The reason being, **I just started to use the library myself**, and really, it's too distant from WebSockets ([websocket](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/websocket), however, the library is built off this) for Socket.io questions to be lumped in that tag. Also, [socket](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/socket) is too broad for Socket.io. If we have people using Socket.io, chances are they don't care too much about [sockets](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sockets).

**Some notes:**

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=socket.io+score%3A1

We have 28 posts (with a score >=1) where socket.io is mentioned.

14 of these are from 2015, and 12 of *these* are questions!

To me, that's enough for a tag. Especially when what we have doesn't really suit it.

Answer (score 5):

I'm no subject expert, but with other tags like [angular.js](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular.js) and [ruby-on-rails](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) for specific libraries/frameworks, I don't see a reason against it.